# How to solve this perticular query in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-normalization

**Problem Statement To Solve:**

1. You need to store employee information (name, age, gender and address) and Project information (name, client name, client city) in database. **Employees can work on multiple projects and a project can have multiple employees. Some employee might not be on any project.**
   Please create table structure for this and necessary constraints, don’t use create table query just structure is important and show primary key and data type of each column.
2. For above scenario write a query for following case:-
   To get list of projects, For each project the details needed in the list are-project name, client name, no. of employee working on project.

**I little bit understand that there is problem in table 1 that is Project table because it's not normalized**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### employee

id|name| age| gender| address

### client

id|name|city

### project

id| name| client_id(FK client.id)

### project_employee_mapping

employee_id (FK employee.id) | project_id (FK project.id)

Query:

```
SELECT p.name, c.client_name, COUNT(pem.employee_id)
FROM project p, project_employee_mapping pem, client c
WHERE pem.project_id = p.id
AND c.id = p.client_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: but i want to ask you that is employee or project tables are normalized or not because they asked me that there is problem in one of the table and given hint about normalization ? Your help will be appreciated ..!!

Comment: Edited my answer to normalize project table

Answer (score 1):

Can’t make much suggestions about constraints or keys, but 
definitely Employee and Projects tables need to be primary keys as Employee ID and Project ID respectively, 
 the gender in employees table could be enum.
Project_employees table is suggested to have a primary key as well, so it can uniquely identify a record in case there are multiple entries of same project or employee ids. That way there won’t be a need of using both of these columns in criteria.

Comment: Did you really have to unearth a 7-month-old homework question to post an answer that starts "Can't make much suggestions..."?

Comment: During search of similar kind of question , I got it and answered.Let me know is it perfect answer or not ?

Comment: It needs a bit more fleshing out, if it stays. The point about constraining gender is good, but in most cases, there are better ways to handle it than with an enum. And some people would argue with the suggestion to give project_employees an ID column. (They'd be rather passionate about it, too; for some people, natural vs surrogate keys is a bit of a religious issue.) I'm not religious about it...but i don't really see the benefit either. (The schema i'm picturing wouldn't *allow* duplicate project<->employee assignments.) It'd be good to show how/where those ideas would make things better.